# Sublime - developer console

Tags: developer-console, sublime

In my company developers are using sublime text 3 and I am new to this, I always use developer console to code. My question is that if I code in developer console will the code even available in sublime text 3 ? Because I don't want to use sublime to code and also as all my company developers using sublime they have/will to see my code in sublime.
Please suggest me some best practices for this.

Comment: Oh my, how were you able to do any really development using the dev console.....lol....Make sure you get MavensMate with Sublime. You will wish you had used it all along

Comment: Yes, we do use mavensmate!! Forgot to mention !!

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Sublime Text myself with Salesforce.

Sublime Text can be used with add-ons like [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/) (I'm assuming this is what they're using. It's probably a decent guess). This effectively lets you use Sublime Text with Salesforce Sandbox/Developer environments to code in Apex/VisualForce, create triggers, components etc...

> My question is that if I code in developer console will the code even available in sublime text 3

You can refresh files from server either on a single file or the Org itself which effectively just downloads the latest code from Salesforce.

If, someone tries to modify a file using Sublime that you modified on the Developer console, they'll see an error like this:

[image]

In which case they need to check the "Diff With Server" to ensure they don't remove any changes you made, for instance.

Of course, if you create new pages, classes etc... They'd need to know to Refresh their local files with those from the server to get those.

It's perfectly doable for some Developers to use Sublime and some to use the Developer Console, as is the case in my organisation.

I do, really recommend Sublime and MavensMate, however! :)

Comment: Second this - Mavens Mate is awesome not just for writing code but for executing anonymous code snippets, running tests, etc.

Comment: Yes we do use mavensmate !! Forgot to mention !

Comment: Everything @Bethany said is also very true. Sublime on its own is just a text editor, Mavensmate is the gateway to your org though and you can use it on Vim, Atom.io as well as Sublime amongst others. Strongly recommend using it above the Developer Console. But really that's down to personal preference. If you decide to stick with the Developer Console, or another Mavensmate supported editor, it won't affect code you've written or will write.